# Customer Review Dataset with Label Classification

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to check my model with the current state of the art models. I want a dataset with customer reviews and their corresponding class assigned. For example, a review like `The car was very badly maintained` should belong to the class - `maintenance` which has already been created before. So essentially, a review and it's corresponding class/label. I also want the current state-of-the-art precision and accuracy values. I can't seem to find both together.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by state-of the-art precision and accuracy values?

Comment: The best accuracy and precision values available out there for that dataset. For example, like http://www.icmc.usp.br/CMS/Arquivos/arquivos_enviados/BIBLIOTECA_113_RT_395.pdf  but this is in 2013. I need an updated version.